# Payment gateway to use for Payout in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

Which Payment gateway is available for **Payout** in Flutter ?

Stripe package available but for **PayIn** only.

Comment: Depends what you mean exactly. Stripe supports payouts(its Connect product). That's mostly handled by backend code. The frontend part is onboarding the user and collecting Know-your-customer information and payout bank details, which in Stipe at least is something you would do with Express on a web page instead of a mobile app, as the easiest-to-integrate option.https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide

Comment: @karllekko package available for Flutter ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Stripe Connect for Payout` but first you need to Onboard your vendor/Merchant to Stripe Connect.
How This will work

- You have to generate a [Express Connect URL](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts)
- This URL will be call from Flutter App In WebView
- Vendor will onboard using this link and you can pay them using
  [Transfer API](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/bank-debit-card-payouts).

You can also Use [RazorPayX](https://razorpay.com/docs/api/x/payouts/) For same purpose.